# issue occurs in join query result display

Tags: mysql, select, zend-framework2, inner-join

```
$select      =  new Select();
        $select ->from(array('h' => 'hotels'),
               array('*'))
        ->join(array('t' => 'roomtypes'),
               'h.id = t.hotel_id')
        ->join(array('c' => 'roomcapacities'),
               'c.roomtype_id = t.id')
        ->where('h.country = '.$country_code )
        ->where('h.state = '.$state)
        ->where('h.city = '.$city)
        ->where('c.no_of_adult = '.$adults);

        print $select->getSqlString();

        $rowset = new DbSelect( $select , $this->tableGateway->getAdapter() );
```

I am new to zend framework. I want to diaply data from these three table. but I could not get proper result of this join query. Where I am doing wrong? Please help me

How to get fields from this resultset? I m getting this result form above query.

```
SELECT "h".*, "t".*, "c".* FROM "hotels" AS "h" INNER JOIN "roomtypes" AS "t" ON "h"."id" = "t"."hotel_id" INNER JOIN "roomcapacities" AS "c" ON "c"."roomtype_id" = "t"."id" WHERE h.country = USA AND h.state = usas2 AND h.city = usac1 AND c.no_of_adult = 3Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect Object
(
    [sql:protected] => Zend\Db\Sql\Sql Object
        (
            [adapter:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter Object
                (
                    [driver:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo Object
                        (
                            [connection:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection Object
                                (
                                    [driver:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo Object
 *RECURSION*
                                    [profiler:protected] => 
                                    [driverName:protected] => mysql
                                    [connectionParameters:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [driver] => pdo_mysql
                                            [dsn] => mysql:dbname=tour_management_system;host=localhost
                                            [driver_options] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [1002] => SET NAMES 'UTF8'
                                                    [1000] => 1
                                                )

                                            [username] => root
                                            [password] => 
                                        )

                                    [resource:protected] => 
                                    [inTransaction:protected] => 
                                )

                            [statementPrototype:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement Object
                                (
                                    [pdo:protected] => 
                                    [profiler:protected] => 
                                    [driver:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo Object
 *RECURSION*
                                    [sql:protected] => 
                                    [isQuery:protected] => 
                                    [parameterContainer:protected] => 
                                    [parametersBound:protected] => 
                                    [resource:protected] => 
                                    [isPrepared:protected] => 
                                )

                            [resultPrototype:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result Object
                                (
                                    [statementMode:protected] => forward
                                    [resource:protected] => 
                                    [options:protected] => 
                                    [currentComplete:protected] => 
                                    [currentData:protected] => 
                                    [position:protected] => -1
                                    [generatedValue:protected] => 
                                    [rowCount:protected] => 
                                )

                            [features:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [platform:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql Object
                        (
                            [resource:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo Object
                                (
                                    [connection:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection Object
                                        (
                                            [driver:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo Object
 *RECURSION*
                                            [profiler:protected] => 
                                            [driverName:protected] => mysql
                                            [connectionParameters:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [driver] => pdo_mysql
                                                    [dsn] => mysql:dbname=tour_management_system;host=localhost
                                                    [driver_options] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [1002] => SET NAMES 'UTF8'
                                                            [1000] => 1
                                                        )

                                                    [username] => root
                                                    [password] => 
                                                )

                                            [resource:protected] => 
                                            [inTransaction:protected] => 
                                        )

                                    [statementPrototype:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement Object
                                        (
                                            [pdo:protected] => 
                                            [profiler:protected] => 
                                            [driver:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo Object
 *RECURSION*
                                            [sql:protected] => 
                                            [isQuery:protected] => 
                                            [parameterContainer:protected] => 
                                            [parametersBound:protected] => 
                                            [resource:protected] => 
                                            [isPrepared:protected] => 
                                        )

                                    [resultPrototype:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result Object
                                        (
                                            [statementMode:protected] => forward
                                            [resource:protected] => 
                                            [options:protected] => 
                                            [currentComplete:protected] => 
                                            [currentData:protected] => 
                                            [position:protected] => -1
                                            [generatedValue:protected] => 
                                            [rowCount:protected] => 
                                        )

                                    [features:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [profiler:protected] => 
                    [queryResultSetPrototype:protected] => Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet Object
                        (
                            [allowedReturnTypes:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => arrayobject
                                    [1] => array
                                )

                            [arrayObjectPrototype:protected] => ArrayObject Object
                                (
                                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [returnType:protected] => arrayobject
                            [buffer:protected] => 
                            [count:protected] => 
                            [dataSource:protected] => 
                            [fieldCount:protected] => 
                            [position:protected] => 0
                        )

                    [lastPreparedStatement:protected] => 
                )

            [table:protected] => 
            [sqlPlatform:protected] => Zend\Db\Sql\Platform\Platform Object
                (
                    [adapter:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter Object
                        (
                            [driver:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo Object
                                (
                                    [connection:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection Object
                                        (
                                            [driver:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo Object
 *RECURSION*
                                            [profiler:protected] => 
                                            [driverName:protected] => mysql
                                            [connectionParameters:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [driver] => pdo_mysql
                                                    [dsn] => mysql:dbname=tour_management_system;host=localhost
                                                    [driver_options] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [1002] => SET NAMES 'UTF8'
                                                            [1000] => 1
                                                        )

                                                    [username] => root
                                                    [password] => 
                                                )

                                            [resource:protected] => 
                                            [inTransaction:protected] => 
                                        )
....
)
```

Comment: what result is proper?

Comment: why is this tagged mysql

Comment: can anyone please give me correct way to execute this query?

Answer (score 0):

To get the results, do as follows:

```
$results = $select->query()->fetchAll();
```

Note that the query function return a Zend_Db_Statement object. Depending on the fetch mode applied to your database adapter, you will get an array or an array of objects or both as your results. To change the fetch mode, use this code:

```
$this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->setFetchMode([fetch mode])
```

where the possible values for fetch mode are enumerated [enter link description here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.select.fetch-mode).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.

```
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use($where) {
            $select->columns(array());
            $select->join(array('h' => 'hotels'),'h.id = roomtypes.hotel_id',array("id","hotel_code"));

return $resultSet->buffer();
```

it gives desired output.